Find $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^m$ using a certain polynomial $p(x)$ and consider its logarithmic derivative
the last time I played around with following problem:
Given:
A polynomial $p(x)$ of degree $n > 0$ with real coefficients and let the n roots be $r_1, r_2, ..., r_n$.
Find:
Powersum S(m) = $\sum_{i=1}^{n} r_i^m$, where $m \in \mathbb{N}$.
Solution: (using polynomial long division, without proof)
$\frac{p´(x)}{p(x)}=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{S(i)}{x^{i+1}}$
New problem:
Set $p(x)=\prod_{k=1}^{n} (x-k)$
Then $S(m) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} i^m $ becomes the power sum of the first natural numbers.
Goal: Find the "known" closed forms for the power sums using the logarithmic derivative.
1. try:
$\frac{p´(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{1}{x-k}$
From here I do not know if this is the correct way.
This approach leads to
$\frac{p´(x)}{p(x)} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{\sum_{j=1}^{n} j^i}{x^{i+1}}$
what I already know and it doesn´t give me a way to e.g. compare coefficients or something like that.
2. try: (my feeling tells me this is the way to go)
Write $p(x) = \prod_{k=1}^{n} (x-k) = \sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k$
where
$c_k = \sum_{1 <= t_1 < t_2 < ... < t_k <= n} \prod_{s=1}^{k} t_s$
And now the big final:
I want to do polynomial long division. The classic way. :D
This should give something promising, shouldn´t it?
$p´(x) = (\sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k)´ = \sum_{k=1}^{n} kc_k x^{k-1} $
Polynomial long division:
$(\sum_{k=1}^{n} kc_k x^{k-1}) : (\sum_{k=0}^n c_k x^k) = ...$
Any hints? Suggestions? My feeling tells me, that one can derive a recursion or maybe the known expression using Bernoulli-polynomials.
My last point:
I am not really interested in finding someone who solves it for me.
Feel free to play around. I need ideas, new inputs.
Why I do this? Because it´s a nice problem. :)
Greetings and thanks for any replies.

You should check Newton's identities

Haha. Thats the way. Thank you very much!!!!
